# Safari, open in another panel

Tags: iphone, safari

When I open a link on Safari, it opens another tab overlapping the original, so to go back to the previous I have to browse all the other tabs. This is uncomfortable because in case I want to read the new link later, I have to make that passage. Is there an option to change card management?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do so:
Settings -> safaris -> open links -> in the background